# How can I run a php file via cronjob?

Tags: php, cron

I want to send an automatic email via cronjob.

I made a file with the name `send_email.php`. If I open it in the browser the email is sucessfully sent. But when I want to open the file via cronjob I get some error messages:

```
   /is/htdocs/user/.../myfolder/send_email.php: line 1: ?php: No such file or directory
   /is/htdocs/user/.../myfolder/send_email.php: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `'includes/config.php''
   /is/htdocs/user/.../myfolder/send_email.php: line 3: `require('includes/config.php'); '
```

My first 3 line in `send_email.php` are:

```
<?php 

require('includes/config.php');
```

Why is this not working?

Comment: How do you call the script from cron? Could you add the line from the cronjob please?

Comment: What does the cron command look like? You probably want something like `... /usr/bin/php your_script.php` instead of just `... your_script.php`

Comment: you want to run cronjob on your localhost OR server ?

Comment: please let me know which server you have, windows / linux, do you have access to cpanel or not?

Comment: Thank you for your answers, my host is hosteurope, so I guess it is a linux server

Comment: this is the full path from the cronjob: `/is/htdocs/user/www/mywebsitefolder/myfolder/send_email.php`

Comment: maybe I cannot include an external config.php? Could this be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

judging from the first error message, you are probably trying to execute your php-scripts as shell-scripts.
try executing the php-binary instead

```
/usr/bin/php /path/to/your/cron.php
```

Comment: ...or prepend a shebang: `#!/usr/bin/php`

Comment: Thank you, but the first part of the path `/is/htdocs/user/` is preset by my host.

Comment: I have another cronjob to mysql dumper that is using almost the same path `/is/htdocs/user/.../myfolder/crondump.pl` and that is working fine.

Comment: well, that cronjob executes a .pl-file, not a .php-file. if you can't directly call your php, you could either use a web-cron or try to prepend your php-cron with #!/usr/bin/php to tell bash what interpreter to use (in this case, php)

Comment: @FranzGleichmann Thank you very much, but what does prebend #!/usr/bin/php mean? Where exactly do I have to put this line?

Comment: prepend= add in front. the first line of your file has to be #!/usr/bin/php - then <?php in the second line

Comment: I tested it, and this was solving my problem! Thank you very much! But I also had to write the code from `require('includes/config.php');` inside  my `send_email.php` otherwise it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Wrong require path probably. You need to check where is send_email.php located relatively to cron working directory. Or you may use lynx for that

```
* * * * * lynx -dump http://domain.tld/send_email.php
```

Comment: There is no need to use something else than just php cli. `php -f /path/to/file.php`

Comment: I think the path is ok because I have another cronjob for mysqldumper `/is/htdocs/user/.../myfolder/crondump.pl` that is working fine